# How is wordpress user validation works?

Tags: wordpress, registration

I have created a custom registration form in the front end using wp_insert_user() function:

```
    $data = array();
    $data['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $data['user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $data['user_pass'] = wp_generate_password ( 12, false );
    $data['role'] = 'pending';

    $user = wp_insert_user( $data );

if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
   $error = $user->get_error_message();
   echo json_encode( array( 'loggedin' => false, 'info' => $error ) );
} else {
   wp_new_user_notification( $user, $data['user_pass'] );
}
```

But I want the user to receive an activation email with activation link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the WordPress codex for the wp_new_user_notification method (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification#Examples), there is an example of how to redefine this function. In that example, functionality is added to send an email to the created user.

Comment: wp_new_user_notification() is currently sending an email to the new user, with the username and password like codex example, but how to send activation link?